# friend class boost mongo_iarchive does not a name a type

Tags: c++, mongodb, serialization, boost, archive

So I had to override some functionality for the boost mongo archive types, and as a result I need these archive types to be a friend of the class I am serializing. However I am running into issues with the compiler finding the archive classes.

```
//#include <boost/archive/mongo_iarchive.hpp>  I dont want these here!
//#include <boost/archive/mongo_oarchive.hpp>

class MyClass
{
  ... //declarations

  friend class boost::archive::mongo_oarchive;
  friend class boost::archive::mongo_iarchive;

  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  ...
};
```

The error I am getting is

> ... error 'mongo_oarchive' in namespace 'boost::archive' does not name a
> type
>
> ... error 'mongo_iarchive' in namespace 'boost::archive' does not
> name a type

but for the serialization::access class there is no issue. I would like to not include the mongo archives at this level because I don't want client code dependencies on the mongo serialization and mongo c++ driver libraries. Note the mongo serialization library is not part of the boost archive/serialization libs it was a custom library (although I don't think that should matter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried forward declaration?

```
namespace boost
{
namespace archive
{
class mongo_oarchive;
class mongo_iarchive;
}
}

class MyClass
{
      ... //declarations

friend class boost::archive::mongo_oarchive;
friend class boost::archive::mongo_iarchive;

friend class boost::serialization::access;
      ...
};
```

Comment: Wow, I figured it would be pretty simple... My question now is why do I need this for the mongo_archive types, but boost::serialization::access; need no forward declaration.

Comment: I had also initially tried the forward declare as simply boost::archive::mongo_archive, but I was getting the same error as before, I assume that is related to finding namespaces or something like that?

Comment: @mike I guess you already included boost/serialization/access.hpp before MyClass.h in your .cpp. That would explain why the compiler already know this type.
And yeah you need the namespace.